# How to add Space between Currency Symbol and Price in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, price, currency

Product Detail, how to add space after currency in magento 2?

**Below is code**

> app/design/frontend/Custom/goshop/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

```
<?php /** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount $block */ ?>

<span class="price-container <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAdjustmentCssClasses() ?>"
        <?php echo $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
    <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
        <span class="price-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayLabel(); ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?php echo $id ?><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif;?>
        <?php echo($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
        data-price-amount="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayValue(); ?>"
        data-price-type="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceType(); ?>"
        class="price-wrapper <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceWrapperCss(); ?>"
        <?php echo $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="price"' : '' ?>>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
    </span>
    <?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
        <?php echo $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->getSchema()): ?>
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayCurrencyCode()?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
</span>
```

[image]

Comment: You can explode string  $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) with RM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can achieve like this:**

```
    <?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile
$id = rand() . time();
?>

<?php
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Render\Amount $block */
$priceproduct = $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool) $block->getIncludeContainer());
if (strpos($priceproduct, 'RM') !== false) {
    $pricearr = explode("RM", $priceproduct);
    $pricespace = $pricearr[0] . "RM " . $pricearr[1];
} else {
    $pricespace = $priceproduct;
}
?>

<span class="price-container <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getAdjustmentCssClasses() ?>"
      <?php echo $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer"' : '' ?>>
          <?php if ($block->getDisplayLabel()): ?>
        <span class="price-label"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayLabel(); ?></span>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <span <?php if ($block->getPriceId()): ?> id="<?php echo $id ?><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceId() ?>"<?php endif; ?>
    <?php echo($block->getPriceDisplayLabel()) ? 'data-label="' . $block->getPriceDisplayLabel() . $block->getPriceDisplayInclExclTaxes() . '"' : '' ?>
                                              data-price-amount="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayValue(); ?>"
                                              data-price-type="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceType(); ?>"
                                              class="price-wrapper <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getPriceWrapperCss(); ?>"
                                              <?php echo $block->getSchema() ? ' itemprop="price"' : '' ?>>
                                              <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $pricespace; ?>
    </span>
    <?php if ($block->hasAdjustmentsHtml()): ?>
        <?php echo $block->getAdjustmentsHtml() ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php if ($block->getSchema()): ?>
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getDisplayCurrencyCode() ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
</span>
```

Answer (score 7):

[image]

Just do like above screenshot in Magento 2 admin and space will be shown in frontend.

Comment: What if we used trim()method while displaying currency symbol

Comment: we can achieve a thing in different ways. For non programming people, my answer is good. For coders, yours. :)

Comment: I did this from admin panel.It working for German language but for english it adds 2 spaces.It already add &nbsp; for english but not for German. How to get resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add space after symbol in whole website you can do this by just changing from admin panel.
Go to `Stores -> Currency Symbols`  and add space after your currency.

Answer (score 0):

I don't Know if is the right way, but I did that removing:

```
<? $block->formatCurrency($block->getDisplayValue(), (bool)$block->getIncludeContainer()) ?>
```

and adding:

```
<span class="money-symbol">
  <?php echo $block->getDisplayCurrencySymbol(); ?>
</span>
<span>
  <?php echo $block->getDisplayValue(); ?>
</span>
```

This way you can control space with css margin or padding applied to class.