# How change currency position from left to right?

Tags: magento2, currency

How can I change currency position?

I referred this, But, I have not it `app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\` What should I do?

Comment: vendor_extension refers to your extension. This means you need to create a new extension where vendor is the module name space or package name and extension refers to module name.

Comment: admin or front ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easy way to change the currency position in the **Locale** (language) you want in Magento 2 admin

---

1. Go from your `root` folder to `/lib/Zend/Locale/Data`
2. Find the `lenguage` file. In my case `es.xml`
3. Look for `<currencyFormat>`

A line just below you will find the `<pattern>`

Change the side of the weird **symbol** and leave it like this:

**Before**

```
<currencyformatlength>
   <currencyformat>
    <pattern>¤ #,##0.00</pattern>
  </currencyformat>
</currencyformatlength>
```

**After**

```
<currencyformatlength>
   <currencyformat>
    <pattern>#,##0.00 ¤</pattern>
  </currencyformat>
</currencyformatlength>
```

Comment: I finded en.xml and I changed it like You but it doesn't work

Comment: are you checking on admin side ?

Comment: Sorry,I do not understand a bit. I changed to  <pattern>#,##0.00 ¤</pattern> and I cleared cache on admin panel.

Comment: are you checking currency symbol at front side or admin side ?

Comment: at front side and admin

Comment: This will reflect on admin side check it after cache flush

Comment: I flushed cache in Cache Management  and clicked ctrl+f5 for sure. Doesnt work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83733/discussion-between-aditya-shah-and-szolv).

Comment: Works. I had to restart my localhost..

Answer (score 1):

You  must have to create a custom extension.

**Also, this module should have:**

1. `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/etc/module.xml`.
2. `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/composer.json`
3. . `app/code/{Vendor}/{Modulename}/registration.php`.

Answer (score 1):

How good is this,

Create `events.xml` file inside your folder.

```
app\code\Vendor\Extension\etc\events.xml
```

Add below code in events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="currency_display_options_forming">
        <observer name="vendor_extension_change_currency_position" instance="Vendor\Extension\Model\Observer\Changecurrencyposition" />
    </event>
</config>
```

Now you need to create observer file inside the extension folder at path `app\code\Vendor\Extension\Model\Observer\Changecurrencyposition.php`

```
<?php        
namespace Vendor\Extension\Model\Observer;    
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;    
class Changecurrencyposition implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {    
        $currencyOptions = $observer->getEvent()->getCurrencyOptions();    
        $currencyOptions->setData('position', \Magento\Framework\Currency::RIGHT);  
        return $this;
    }    
}
```

Run the following command and you are done.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: hello @Kazim, this code is working, but can we add one space then symbol to show  on right hand side, ex: 100 $.

Comment: Go to Stores -> Currency Symbols. Add space before or after your currency.
For reference https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/211617/45214

Comment: okay thank you, let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/frontend**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <preference for="Magento\Directory\Model\Currency" type="VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Currency" />

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model**

**Currency.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

class Currency extends \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency
{
    public function formatTxt($price, $options = [])
    {
        if (!is_numeric($price)) {
            $price = $this->_localeFormat->getNumber($price);
        }
        $price = sprintf("%F", $price);

        return $this->_localeCurrency->getCurrency($this->getCode())->toCurrency($price, $options);
    }

}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

    <event name="currency_display_options_forming">
        <observer name="change_currency_position" instance="VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer\ChangeCurrencyPosition" />
    </event>

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Observer**

**ChangeCurrencyPosition.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ChangeCurrencyPosition implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $currencyOptions = $observer->getEvent()->getCurrencyOptions();
        $currencyOptions->setData('position', \Magento\Framework\Currency::LEFT);
        //$currencyOptions->setData('position', \Magento\Framework\Currency::RIGHT);
        return $this;
    }
}
```